# How to iterate multiple labels in a data frame?

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I have a file list as:

```
filelist = ['file1','file2',file3']
```

I am trying to make a datframe including file lists with "n" iteration.(n is same for all files) What I'm looking for is as follow:

```
"Labels"
file1
file1
file1
.
.
file2
file2
file2
.
.
file3
file3
file3
.
.
```

Can anyone please advise how to build this dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming n=3 and using list comprehension :

```
import pandas as pd

filelist = ['file1','file2','file3']
filelist1=[f for f in filelist for i in range(3)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(filelist1, columns=['labels'])

print(df1)
```

output:

```
labels
0  file1
1  file1
2  file1
3  file2
4  file2
5  file2
6  file3
7  file3
8  file3
```

Answer (score 0):

use pandas as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
filelist = ['file1','file2','file3']
df = pd.DataFrame({"labels":filelist})
df
```

the output as follow:

```
  labels
0  file1
1  file2
2  file3
```

Comment: And how to repeat each file in a data frame?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to do this

```
def createDF(input_list, n_iteration):
    data = sorted(input_list * n_iteration)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Labels': data})
    return df

createDF(filelist, 3)
```

Output

```
  Labels
0  file1
1  file1
2  file1
3  file2
4  file2
5  file2
6  file3
7  file3
8  file3
```

Comment: Thanks @thecruisy! Still works for me however @Mehrdad replied earlier. Appreciate anyhow!